# Is it safe to assign list comprehension to the original list?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is the following safe?

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x = [y+5 for y in x]
```

Does the list comprehension evaluate first, creating a new list, and then assign that new list to x?
I was told once that changing a list while iterating over it is an unsafe operation.

Comment: Changing a list while iterating is not the same thing as iterating and assigning the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't changing the list while iterating over it, you are creating a completely **new** list and then once it has been evaluated, you are binding it to the name `x` so everything is safe.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, it's safe.

As you hinted, the right-hand side is evaluated first, and then *its result* (an entirely new list) is assigned to the name `x`.  You're right that it's unsafe to change a list while iterating over it, but that's not happening in your code sample, so no worries.